# Read every line on multiple files simultaneously

Tags: python, text, file-io

I have 'n' ".txt" files in a folder, I wanna open them at the same time and read every first line of each file in a loop, then every second line ...

My files are written like this :

```
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
```

I've used

```
file = fileinput.input(files=("text_{}.txt".format(i)))
for line in file:
    for ch in line:
        print file.readline()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just how can I do that ?

Comment: Work your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) practicing the examples given. Eventually you will get ideas for solving your problem. Try some of those ideas out; if you get stuck, search around and see if someone has solved that problem; come back and ask about things you can't solve on your own

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for you response, but if I want to loop over multiple files at one time do I have to use fileinput module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to read the contents of every file in memory,

```
FILES = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_handles = {filename: open(filename, 'r') for filename in FILES}
    while 1:
        for filename, file in file_handles.items():
            line = next(file, None)
            if line is not None:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                print(line)
            else:
                file.close()
                # file_handles.pop(filename)
        if line is None:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open multiple files at once, and easily store them in an array to iterate over and perform 'readline' on. Its important to remember to close all the files you open too, since it can become habit to rely on the "with" statement to close them for you (which isn't practical for this specific scenario). Example code:

```
filenames = ["File1.txt", "File2.txt"]
file_objs = []

for name in filenames:
    file_objs.append(open(name, "r"))

while file_objs:
    for file in file_objs:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            file_objs.pop(file_objs.index(file)).close()
        else:
            ...
```